# Different regression models in one research project?

Tags: regression, modeling, poisson-regression

I'm working on a research project on alcohol behaviours where I am looking at 2 outcomes: 1) number of drinks; 2) preference (5-point Likert scale, ordinal).

There are two things I'm confused about:
A) Should I be treating the 'number of drinks' as a count variable or ordinal?

B) If I use a Poisson regression for 'number of drinks' and ordinal regression to look at 'preference', is it common to use two different regression models in one research project/article? I am asking because in general, most journal articles I've read seem to only use type of regression even when there are multiple outcomes.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You can definitely do both in one article. If the two models share parameters, this is an instance of multi-task learning. AFAIK ordinal regression requires you to bound the number of drinks to a finite, ordered set. Treating it as a count gives you more flexibility in that regard.

Comment: I suppose finiteness isn't the point I was trying to emphasize—you wouldn't drink infinite drinks, after all. It's that you have to choose the set of 'legal' numbers of drinks in advance.

Comment: Okay that makes sense, thanks @AryaMcCarthy!